# Cannot run self-contained app on Raspberry Pi - No such file or directory

Tags: raspberry-pi, .net-6.0

I am following these [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/iot/deployment#deploying-a-self-contained-app) to run my `.NET 6` console app on my Raspberry Pi and the last point (4.b) is causing me some troubles.

After deploying my app to the raspberry pi, I am running the following commands:

```
pi@babyminder:~/babyminder $ chmod +x PoC.BabyMinder.Gpio
pi@babyminder:~/babyminder $ ls -l
total 18668
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi     9824 Jul 19 23:09 libSystem.IO.Ports.Native.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 19089322 Jul 19 23:09 PoC.BabyMinder.Gpio
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi    10892 Jul 19 23:09 PoC.BabyMinder.Gpio.pdb
pi@babyminder:~/babyminder $ ./PoC.BabyMinder.Gpio
-bash: ./PoC.BabyMinder.Gpio: No such file or directory
```

Here is the content of my `pubxml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121.
-->
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <PublishDir>bin\Release\net6.0\publish\linux-arm\</PublishDir>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>linux-arm</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Here is the scp command I used:

```
scp -r bin/Release/net6.0/publish/linux-arm/* pi@babyminder:/home/pi/babyminder/
```

I don't understand what is going wrong with my setting?

Here are some additional information:

- I only know the very basic of unix
- My Raspberry Pi is a fresh installation of Raspberry Pi OS Lite (64 bits)
- `chmod 777` does not work either
- If I omit the chmod command, I get the following error when I try to execute the file: `-bash: ./PoC.BabyMinder.Gpio: Permission denied` (so the file does exist)
- Looks like the answer is [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101429/no-such-file-or-directory-when-executing-a-cross-compiled-program-on-a-raspber) but I honestly do not understand everything ...
- Deploying a framework-dependent app works like a charm (previous paragraph in the first link provided)

Comment: What does `file` report your program is?  Is it different than a program that works (e.g., `file /bin/bash`)?

Comment: @StephenNewell : I am sorry I do not understand the question. You can consider me a very beginner in all this unix stuff ...

Comment: @StephenNewell I found out. The command `file` does not exists on my raspberry : `$ file PoC.BabyMinder.Gpio
-bash: file: command not found`

Comment: I ran `ldd` as suggested in the link I provided in the end of my post: `$ ldd PoC.BabyMinder.Gpio
        not a dynamic executable`. As suspected, it looks like a cross-compile failure. But I don't know how to fix it with `.NET6`

Comment: Could it be because I installed an arm64 OS and the dotnet SDK only supports arm32?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you select the correct compiler for your Raspberry Pi. For a 32bit installation, use `linux-arm` and for a 64bit installation use `linux-arm64`.

You can also check to see if you compiled correctly by running `ldd <MyApplication>` from the shell on your Raspberry Pi. A properly compiled file will give you output that looks like this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/var/services/ $ ldd MyApplication
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000007fb7bba000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000007fb7185000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x0000007fb7171000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x0000007fb7147000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x0000007fb712f000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000007fb710b000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000007fb6f33000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x0000007fb6e88000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000007fb6d13000)
        /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000007fb7b8a000)
```

Whereas incorrectly compiled files will say `not a dynamic executable`

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed a 32 bit OS and it works now ...

According to this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101429/no-such-file-or-directory-when-executing-a-cross-compiled-program-on-a-raspber), I guess the .NET SDK is providing some wrong arguments to the cross-compiler (I am a little bit out of my field here so I'm only guessing ^^).